Need opinion on water infiltration in basement
Minor trace of water infiltration prompted me to open the wall in basement toilet. This is the state of the foundation behind that wall.
Anyone could provide any insights on the state of that foundation wall?

Thank you

What is the drainage like on the other side of the wall? Do you have gutters and downspouts that move water away from the foundation?

Most of the time, foundation water leaks/damp walls need to be fixed on the outside.  Usually by digging and sealing.  Sometimes you can move gutter downspouts away from the house and/or fix the grading so water flows away.

A gutter is dropping water about a feet from the wall. Which I assume is the issue and will be fixed. Grading also needs to be done to pull water away from the house.
How would you define the state of that foundation? Does it look like it needs repair?

It needs some mildew cleaned off, but otherwise it looks ok for now. No signs of serious deterioration.

Thank you @RMDman, appreciate your input.

Will need to touch the blocks to see.  Cement blocks should be quite hard if dragging a screwdriver across them.  If the screwdriver digs in, that is not good.

@crip659 Got it! I will do that test and see. Thank you!
